# Why $\int f_0 \mbox{d}(F_0+F_1)=\int f_0 \mbox{d}F_0+\int f_0 \mbox{d} F_1=1$ should be true?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

A measure $\mu$ dominates another measure $\nu$ whenever $\mu=0$ implies $\nu=0$. If I would like to take the integral of a measurable function $f_0$, say the density function of the probability measure $F_0$ over the real numbers w.r.t. a dominating measure say $\mu=F_0+F_1$ ($F_1$ being another probability measure), I will have $$\int f_0 \mbox{d}\mu=1$$ If $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure the result is obvious to me. Whenever $\mu=F_0+F_1$, I dont understand why $$\int f_0 \mbox{d}(F_0+F_1)=\int f_0 \mbox{d}F_0+\int f_0 \mbox{d} F_1=1$$ should be true. I have some missing information here. Does somebody know why it should it be the case? Here is the related [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177699803): just the first page where this definition is made.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think this can be true as stated. Consider, say, $F_1=F_0$, then if $\int f_0 d F_0 = 1$ then $\int f_0 d (F_0 + F_1) = 2$. Are you sure you do not have that $F_0$ and $F_1$ are mutually singular?

Comment: @Ian it is also not guaranteed that $\int f_0 d F_0=1$. What I know is that $F_0$ and $F_1$ are some distinct probability measures. What does mutually singular mean? I have this from one paper. The author defines a dominating measure and take various integrals. I guess the choice of measure here doesnt change anything but my information here is unfortunately superficial..

Comment: $m$ and $n$ are mutually singular if $X = A \cup B$, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $m$ is zero on all measurable subsets of $A$ and $n$ is zero on all measurable subsets of $B$. For example, the Lebesgue measure and any discrete measure are mutually singular.

Comment: @Ian I dont thing so. I am sure that both are probability measures. Here the first page http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177699803